# update multiple rows with different values on single button click

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a grid view, which displays the monthly items purchased by our registerd dealers. On button click event, all the items displayed in the grid view row wise should be made purchased by the dealer on one single click. This is the case of bulk update.

grid view code::

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridCustomer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID">
<Columns> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PURCHASED_MONTH" HeaderText="MONTH" ></asp:BoundField> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ITEM_NAME" HeaderText="ITEM NAME"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="PAYABLE_AMOUNT" HeaderText="PAYABLE AMOUNT"></asp:BoundField>     
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The number of rows is dynamic, sometimes single row sometimes multiple.

The table data ::

```
ID      MONTH   ITEM_ID STATUS      PAYABLE_AMOUNT  
1       4       155     1           
2       5       159     1           
3       6       256     1
```

In the `UPDATE` statement the `WHERE CLAUSE` will be `ID`. According to cases, I will have single ID or multiple IDs. For example,

```
update tbl_wholesome_purchase set STATUS = 2 WHERE ID = 1 but in some case ID = 1, 2, 3... also.
```

**How can I create such update case stored procedure in which the WHERE CLAUSE parameter is dynamic** ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server 2016 or newer ?.

In that case you can use the [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to get a very easy solution, passing the IDs as a single comma-separated string.

```
DECLARE @ids varchar(max) = '4,7,9,25'

UPDATE tbl_wholesome_purchase SET status = 2 
WHERE id IN (SELECT value FROM split_string(@ids, ','))
```

Another solution is to pass the ids already as a list, on [table valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15). You will need to follow the documentation of ASP.NET about [how to call them on dot net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).

```
CREATE TYPE ListIDs AS TABLE ( id int );
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo. update_wholesome_purchase 
   @ids ListIDs READONLY
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE tbl_wholesome_purchase SET status = 2 
   WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM @ids);
END
GO
```